# always Hive Job running in-process local Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I set this property in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.mode.local.auto</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Hive always runs the hadoop job locally.

```
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 55
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [HIVE-2585](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2585),Going forward **`Hive`** will assume that the **`metastore`** is operating in **`local mode`** if the configuration property **`hive.metastore.uris`** is **`unset`**, and **`will assume remote mode otherwise`**.

Ensure following property is set in **`Hive-site.xml`**:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value><URIs of metastore server>:9083</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name> hive.metastore.local</name>
    <value>false</value> 
</property>
```

The **`hive.metastore.local`** property is no longer supported **`as of Hive 0.10`**; setting **`hive.metastore.uris`** is sufficient to indicate that you are using a remote metastore.

**EDIT:**

**Starting with release 0.7**, **Hive** also supports a mode to run map-reduce jobs in **local-mode automatically**. The relevant options are **`hive.exec.mode.local.auto`**, **`hive.exec.mode.local.auto.inputbytes.max`**, and **`hive.exec.mode.local.auto.tasks.max`**:

```
hive> SET hive.exec.mode.local.auto=false;
```

Note that this feature is disabled by default. If enabled, **`Hive`** analyzes the size of each **`map-reduce job`** in a query and may run it **`locally`** if the following **`thresholds`** are satisfied:

```
1. The total input size of the job is lower than: hive.exec.mode.local.auto.inputbytes.max (128MB by default)

2. The total number of map-tasks is less than: hive.exec.mode.local.auto.tasks.max (4 by default)

3. The total number of reduce tasks required is 1 or 0.
```

**So for queries over small data sets**, or for queries with multiple **`map-reduce jobs`** where the input to subsequent jobs is substantially smaller (because of reduction/filtering in the prior job), **`jobs may be run locally`**.

Reference: [Hive Getting started](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted)

Comment: Thanks your reply.
I set `hive.metastore.uris` property in hive-site.xml.
And I use hive 1.2.1 version.
But still run `Job running in-process (local Hadoop)`
what's wrong in my hive?

Comment: My data size is about 70MB *2 / partition.
I have 90+ partitions. I guess Is data size too small?

Comment: What's configuration in mapred-site.xml? check the value of hive.exec.mode.local.auto by running hive> set hive.exec.mode.local.auto

Comment: I have updated the answer, see the EDIT in the answer.

Comment: `hive> set hive.exec.mode.local.auto` -> `hive.exec.mode.local.auto=false`

Comment: And I think I have something wrong in my hadoop configure. Because I run same hive job in spark. Spark took 5 min. But in Hadoop took 20min. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, it depends on input size. in your case it's small (70MB).

Comment: I set 2 properties in mapred-site.xml. `mapreduce.jobhistory.address` and `mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address`

Comment: @Minwoo is this issue resolved? Please post how you resolved this issue

Comment: @Mohan Actually In my case I decided using spark intead of Map-reduce.

Comment: thanks. Based on my research, spark execution engine is not yet production ready.